# Setting a bool published attribute with @published

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have the following .dart component

```dart
@CustomTag('description-form')
class DescriptionForm extends PolymerElement {
  @observable Map<String, dynamic> datamap = {};
  @observable String description = '';

  @published
  String get label => readValue(#label);
  set label(String value) => writeValue(#label, value);

  @published
  bool get isVisible => readValue(#isVisible);
  set isVisible(bool value) => writeValue(#isVisible, value);

  DescriptionForm.created() : super.created();

  void publish() {
    datamap['description'] = description;
  }

  @override
  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    datamap['receiver'] = dataset['receiver'];
  }
}
```

To use the published attributes, I would do the following in a form

```dart
  <description-form
    label = 'Others'
    isVisible = false
    data-receiver = 'shared| description-form --> dynamic-chkbx'>
  </description-form>
```

While label is resolved, isVisible does not. 
What is the correct mechanism to set a bool that is published using `@published`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, boolean attributes work based on whether they're present or not present. So if you set up the property in your class like so:

```dart
@PublishedProperty(reflect: true) bool isVisible = true;
```

Then you can use it in the HTML like this:

```dart
  <description-form
    label = 'Others'
    isVisible
    data-receiver = 'shared| description-form --> dynamic-chkbx'>
  </description-form>
```

When `isVisible` is present on the tag, it's `true` in the class, and changing the class's property to `false` removes the attribute on the tag (thanks to `reflect: true`).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

In response to @montyr75 s answer.

`PublishedProperty(reflect: true)` is necessary when you want the value of the field available in the DOM for example to be used in CSS selectors. If it is only used in code `@published` is fine. (still not entirely sure about this though).

If you want a boolean attribute that indicates `true` by the presence of the attribute and `false` by the a absence use a question mark like `<description-form isVisible?="{{reference}}">`

I tried a boolean attribute like you use it in your code and it just worked for me.

Another hint:
If you want changes in your collections to take effect in the view you should make the collections observable
`@observable Map<String, dynamic> datamap = toObservable({});`

Comment: Two great hints Gunter! What does reference in <description-form isVisible?="{{reference}}"> refers to? true | false? Or another reference that assigns true | false?

Comment: Reference is just an observable field in the Polymer element. What I tried to point out is the `?` at the end of the attribute name, which results in an attribute `isVisible` to be added/removed in the DOM when the field `reference` becomes `true`/`false` whereas with `isVisible="{{reference}}"` without the `?` results in `isVisible="true"`/`isVisible="false"` when the field `reference` becomes `true`/`false`.

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer your question:

The string from label will be correctly resolved. If you have a boolean published attribute `isVisible` just use `<description-form></description-form>` if you want isVisible to be `false` and  `<description-form isVisible></description-form>` if you want it to be `true`.